# How to find file in ftp by php?

Tags: php, ftp

I want to find files in ftp.

We have a tree path like this: ftp://documents.mycomp.com/mycomp/2017/companies/code/file.pdf
and the php source you can find here: ftp://documents.mycomp.com/php/get_File.php.

On the testing location, my pc, it works fine. But finding on the ftp-server is a problem...

```
$directory = "../mycomp/2017/compX/57719/" 
$root = getcwd();
$result = scandir($root . substr($directory, 2), SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING); 
foreach($result as $fileName)
{
   ...; 
   $files[]  = substr($directory, 2) . $fileName; 
}
...

Result:
$files[x] = "../mycomp/2017/compX/57719/premiumList.pdf"
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your problem.

Though if you want to use `scandir` on the FTP server, you have to pass in an `ftp://` URL like:

```
$result = scandir("ftp://example.com/directory/to/list/");
```

You of course need to have [fopen wrappers enabled](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) (it's enabled by default).

Alternatively, use [FTP function `ftp_nlist`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php).